# WPF - Properties of ItemsSource to Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

### Background

I am making a custom control that has multiple ListBox's. I want to make this control MVVM compliant, so I am keeping any XAML and the code behind agnostic with respect to any ViewModel. One ListBox is simply going to be a list of TextBox's while the other is going to have a canvas as the host to display the data graphically. Both of these ListBox's are children of this custom control.
Pseudo example for the custom control template:

```xml
<CustomControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox1 Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ListBox2 Grid.Column="1"/>
</CustomControl>
```

The code behind for this custrom control would have a dependency property that will serve as the ItemsSource, fairly standard stuff:

```cs
public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as UserControl1;
    if (control != null)
        control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
}
```

### Where I am stuck

Because the two ListBox's are using the same data source but just display the data differently, I want the ItemsSource defined as one of the the parent view's dependency properties to be the ItemsSource for the two children. From the ViewModel side, this items source can be some sort of `ObservableCollection<ChildViewModels>`, or IEnumerable, or whatever it wants to be.

**How can I point to properties from the ItemsSource's ViewModel to dependency properties of the child views?**

I was hoping to get something similar to how it could be done outside of a custom view:

Example Parent ViewModel(omitting a lot, assume all functioning):

```cs
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels;
}
```

Example ViewModel (omitting `INotifyPropertyChanged` and associated logic):

```cs
public class ChildViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}   
}
```

Example control (ommitting setting the DataContext, assume set properly):

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}">
    <ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Description}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can I do something similar where I can pass the properties from the ItemsSource to the child views on a custom control?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you bind both ListBox elements to the custom control's ItemsSource property? You should also consider to make the ItemsSoure property of type IList rather than IEnumerable to improve binding performance.

Comment: Thats along the lines of what I am thinking. Following that potential solution, that would basically be creating a collection of objects as a dependency property - of type IList<T> as you suggested. How would properties of object T then be passed to the child views? In the above example, Name as Description are the properties that would need to be passed to the child views. Maybe a dependency property pointing at a property of the ItemsSource? Seems messy

Comment: The problem seems so trivial that I'm sthinking I misunderstood you. You have two ListBox elements inside your UserControl. This UserControl has a ItemsSource property that is bound to its DataContext. You want the ItemsSource to be set to the ItemsSource property of the two inner ListBox elements, is that correct?

Comment: The ItemsSource property should be of type IList and not IList<T>.

Comment: 3 custom controls; one parent and two children. I am looking to have one point of entry for the data; being a single ItemsSource on the parent. The items source will be of type IList, which will represent the list of objects passed into the ItemsSource from the data context. The children will display data - public properties of the objects on the ItemsSource. Because the children are custom controls, these data entities will need to be bound to their own dependency properties on the child controls. I am unsure on how to pass the ItemsSource properties to the children

Comment: 1) the two child controls are those that contain ListBox controls? 2) And the two child controls are the content of the parent? 3) And why don't you merge the two child controls with the parent?

Comment: 1) Correct: one of the children is a simple list of text, the other child is a canvas where we draw shapes to display the bound data graphically. One child in column 0 and the other in column 1. 2) Correct. I initially wanted to put both in a common parrent because there is a lot of view-specific coordination that will need to be done between the two children. 3) I could, but they would still need to be two distinct ListBox's - one child has an item template, the other uses a canvas as a host

Comment: 1) But how does your posted XAML with a UserControl that contains two ListBox controls relate to this?

Comment: If you have two controls, where each contains a ListBox, then each control must have a ItemsSource property in order to bind the ListBox to it (internally). Externally this property must bind to a third itemsSource property on the parent control. Then the parent control's property binds to the DataContext (view model class).

Comment: because the panel of the child views are list views with an associated code behind. I could have very well named them <childview1/> <childview2/> where those are <childview1> <listbox>stuff</listbox></childview1>

Comment: Ok. ListBox1  is a UserControl. Then spend each a ItemsSource property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, then here is an example.

1. Add properties for element templates in both lists and style for Canvas.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2022.SO.jgrmn
{
    public class TwoListControl : Control
    {
        static TwoListControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TwoListControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TwoListControl)));
        }

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(ItemsSource),
                typeof(IEnumerable),
                typeof(TwoListControl),
                new PropertyMetadata((d, e) => ((TwoListControl)d).OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue)));

        private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public DataTemplate TemplateForStack
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(TemplateForStackProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TemplateForStackProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateForStackProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(TemplateForStack),
                typeof(DataTemplate),
                typeof(TwoListControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public DataTemplate TemplateForCanvas
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(TemplateForCanvasProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TemplateForCanvasProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateForCanvasProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(TemplateForCanvas),
                typeof(DataTemplate),
                typeof(TwoListControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public Style StyleForCanvas
        {
            get { return (Style)GetValue(StyleForCanvasProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StyleForCanvasProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StyleForCanvasProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(StyleForCanvas),
                typeof(Style),
                typeof(TwoListControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

In the theme (Themes/Generic.xaml), set bindings to these properties:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:jgrmn="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.jgrmn">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type jgrmn:TwoListControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type jgrmn:TwoListControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
                                 ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding TemplateForStack}"/>
                        <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
                                 ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding TemplateForCanvas}"
                                 ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding StyleForCanvas}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window with an example of use:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.jgrmn.TwoListWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.jgrmn"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TwoListWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <Point>15 50</Point>
            <Point>50 150</Point>
            <Point>150 50</Point>
            <Point>150 150</Point>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:TwoListControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <local:TwoListControl.TemplateForStack>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Point ({0} {1})">
                                <Binding Path="X"/>
                                <Binding Path="Y"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:TwoListControl.TemplateForStack>
            <local:TwoListControl.TemplateForCanvas>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:TwoListControl.TemplateForCanvas>
            <local:TwoListControl.StyleForCanvas>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </local:TwoListControl.StyleForCanvas>
        </local:TwoListControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must spend all participating controls a `ItemsSource` property. The idea is to delegate the source collection from the parent to the child controls and finally to the `ListBox`. The ItemsSource properties should be a dependency property of type `IList` and not `IEnumerable`. This way you force the binding source to be of type `IList` which improves the binding performance.

To allow customization of the actual displayed items, you must either
a) spend every control a `ItemTemplate` property of type `DataTemplate` and delegate it to the inner most `ListBox.ItemTemplate` (similar to the `ItemsSource` property) or
b) define the template as a resource (implicit template, which is a key less `DataTemplate`).

The example implements a):

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ParentViewModel />
  </Window.DataCOntext>

  <CustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}">
    <CustomControl.ItemsTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Description}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </CustomControl.ItemsTemplate>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox1 Grid.Column="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemsSource}"
              ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemTemplate}" />
    <ListBox2 Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemsSource}"
              ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemTemplate}" />
  </CustomControl>
</Window>
```

Inside the child controls (`ListBox1` and `ListBox2`):

```xml
<UserControl>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemsSource}"
           ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemTemplate}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: By using {Binding Name} in the custom control's template, you are making a hard reference to the view model. The view's template should not have any reference whatsoever to the viewmodel

Comment: Where you define {binding name}, i want to make in the parent view, and have it pass down to the child views

Comment: I have updated the example. You must also define the ItemTemplate on the parent and delegate it to the child controls and finally to the ListBox.

Comment: this does not answer the question. This just duplicates the same ItemsTemplate on two duplicated controls. Yes, this does share a common ItemsSource between the two controls, but fundamentally puts it into one location - that is the shared ItemsTemplate. I am looking for ways to share a common ItemsSource between two templates; two custom controls where one is a list of elements (lets call it textblocks) and the other draws shapes on a canvas.

Comment: I think. I gave you the answer. I gave you an example using a single ListBox. The essence of this answer is that the parent control is the scope where the DataContext is known/set. This is where you can define the templates (see example). You would have to address each of ListBox elements with a dedicated ItemTemplate property. You could name them ListViewItemTemplate and GraphicViewItemTemplate (I'm sure you find more precise names). To make your code simpler, you  should really consider to move/merge everything into a single control. I don't see the benefit of your current design choice.